# Regex for PR naming convention

Tags: regex, string, github

I want to write a regex to enforce PR naming convention, like this:

`[JIRA-1234] My PR description name`

Where `1234` can be any number of any length of digits, and `My PR description name` can be any string, as long as the length is greater than zero.

How can I achieve this? So far I have tried:

`^(?=[JIRA)(.*)(?=])[a-zA-Z]*`

Comment: Like this? `^\[JIRA-\d+]\s*\w.*` https://regex101.com/r/YSY88m/1

Comment: It can probably be just `^\[JIRA-[0-9]+] .+` or `^\[JIRA-[0-9]+] +[^ ].*`

Comment: this perhaps help: ^\[JIRA\-\d+\][\sa-zA-Z]+$      https://regex101.com/r/9lQSP0/1

Comment: Did any solution work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the JIRA part followed by optional whitespace chars and start with at least a single word character and the rest of the line to not match ony whitespace chars for the description name.

```
^\[JIRA-\d+]\s*\w.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4Vex3a/1)

Or match 0+ whitespace chars without a newline, and if the description can also start with another char than a word character, you can match a non whitespace char using `\S`

```
^\[JIRA-\d+][^\S\r\n]*\S.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RzMg9b/1)

Comment: \s*\w.*  it will accept number also.. but as per op it should be string with greater than 0 lenth

Comment: @ShekharKhairnar This part `\s*\w.*` Matches at least a single word character and must be therefore longer than 0 and it will not match only whitespace chars as a description.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `^^\[JIRA\-\d+\](?:\s{1}[a-zA-Z]+)+$`

`\[JIRA\-\d+\]`     maches [JIRA-1234]

`(?:\s{1}[a-zA-Z]+)+`     non capturing group of(single while space followed by one or more character) at least one or more times

[regex101 - demo](https://regex101.com/r/9lQSP0/3)